# how to make squeue sort by submittime

Tags: slurm

I am trying to understand how to use squeue to sort by submittime.
I know I can use queue as following so it will show the submittime,

```
squeue -O "stepid:6,username:8,account:7,name:53,partition:15,submittime:20"
```

but how do I make it to sort by the sumbittime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Normally, you would use the `--sort` option of `squeue`:

```
   -S <sort_list>, --sort=<sort_list>
          Specification  of  the  order  in which records should be reported.  This uses the same field specification as the <output_format>.  Multiple sorts may be performed by
          listing multiple sort fields separated by commas.  The field specifications may be preceded by "+" or "-" for ascending (default) and  descending  order  respectively.
          For  example, a sort value of "P,U" will sort the records by partition name then by user id.  The default value of sort for jobs is "P,t,-p" (increasing partition name
          then within a given partition by increasing job state and then decreasing priority).  The default value of sort for job steps is "P,i" (increasing partition name  then
          within a given partition by increasing step id).
```

The submission time in the 'output_format' (the format to use with `-o, --format` -- not the one you are using which is used with `-O, --Format`) is `%V`.

Unfortunately on my system this leads to an error. Not sure why that is.

```
$ /usr/bin/squeue -S V
             JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
squeue: error: Invalid sort specification: V
```

So I guess you should simply use the `sort` utility:

```
squeue -O "stepid:6,username:8,account:7,name:53,partition:15,submittime:20" | sort -k4
```

This will work as the time format allows comparison by alphanumerical order.